# Почему не происходит анимация прямоугольника после завершения анимации окружности?

Tags: svg, svg-animation

1. кликнуть по оранжевому кругу
2. Оранжевый круг 2 раза повторяет анимацию после чего должна быть анимация прямоугольника
3. Анимация прямоугольника не происходит почему ?

```html
<svg version="1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" stroke='black' width='500' height='500' style='border: 1px solid black;'>
  <circle r="30" cx="30" cy="50%" fill='orange' id='a' stroke='none' />
  <rect id='b' x="20" y="100" width="50" height="50" fill="#0099cc"></rect>

  <animate
   xlink:href='#a'
   attributeName='cx'
   from='10' to='470'
   dur='2s'
   repeatCount='2'
   begin='click'
   fill='freeze'
   id='circ_anim'
    /> 
  <animate xlink:href='#b'
   attributeName='x'
   from='0'
   to='470'
   dur='3s'
   begin='circ_anim.repeat(2)'
   fill='freeze'
   >
</svg>
```

Comment: У меня все работает

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Оранжевый круг 2 раза повторяет анимацию после чего должна быть
>   анимация прямоугольника

Не работает как надо, потому что нужно по другому написать условие запуска анимации

Для первой анимации (оранжевого круга id='circ_anim') стоит параметр repeatCount ="2" Это правильно, - анимация повторится 2 раза

Вторая анимация, - для прямоугольника должна начаться после завершения двух циклов первой анимации, то есть первая анимация окружности должна полностью завершиться, так и пишем условие запуска анимации прямоугольника  `begin="circ_anim.end"`

```html
<svg version="1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"  stroke='black' width="50%" height="50%" viewBox="0 0 500 300" style='border: 1px solid black;'>
<circle id='a' r="30" cx="30" cy="50" fill='orange'  stroke='none' />
<rect id='b' x="0" y="100" width="50" height="50" fill="#0099cc"></rect>

<animate
xlink:href='#a'
attributeName='cx'
from='30' to='470'
dur='2s'
repeatCount='2'
begin='click'
fill='freeze'
id='circ_anim'
/>
<animate xlink:href='#b'
attributeName='x'
from='0'
to='450'
dur='3s'
begin='circ_anim.end'
fill='freeze'
/>
</svg>
```

**В качестве бонуса условия запуска анимации сделаем чуть-чуть посложнее:**

1. Оранжевый круг после клика 2 раза повторяет анимацию
   `repeatCount="2"`
2. После завершения анимации круга прямоугольник 3 раза повторяет анимацию
   `begin='circ_anim.end'`repeatCount="3"`
3. Зацикливание, то есть снова начинается анимация оранжевого круга

`begin="click;rect_anim.end"` , где `click` самый первый запуск анимации круга **;** `rect_anim.end`- второй запуск анимации круга после завершения анимации прямоугольника и снова всё повторяется.

**Note**

Обратите внимание на точку с запятой в команде запуска анимации `begin` она разделяет два условия запуска. Таких условий может быть несколько и каждое условие необходимо разделять точкой с запятой.

*Анимация начинается после клика по оранжевому кругу*

```html
<svg version="1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"  stroke='black' width='50%' height='50%' viewBox="0 0 500 300" style='border: 1px solid black;'>
<circle id='a' r="30" cx="30" cy="50" fill='orange'  stroke='none' />
<rect id='b' x="0" y="100" width="50" height="50" fill="#0099cc"></rect>

<animate
xlink:href='#a'
attributeName='cx'
from='30' to='470'
dur='2s'
repeatCount='2'
begin='click;rect_anim.end'
fill='freeze'
id='circ_anim'
/>
<animate  xlink:href='#b'
attributeName='x'
from='0'
to='450'
repeatCount='3'
dur='1.5s'
begin='circ_anim.end'
fill='freeze'
id='rect_anim'
/>
</svg>
```